# Code works in main but not in other classes

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I'm trying to use `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` in my Qt application but for some reason I can't get it to work. I have the following code which will work if I execute it from the `main` class but not from a controller class which inherits `QObject`:

```
 QGraphicsScene scene;
 scene.setSceneRect(0,0,200,200);
 scene.setBackgroundBrush(Qt::blue);
 QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
 view->setScene(&scene);
 view->show();
```

If I do it in `main` the scene is blue but if I do it in the other class the scene is white. What is going on?

Comment: To start with, this piece of code will not compile as `view` is a pointer, but you are using `.` to access members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to this:

```
{
QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene();//note that we allocate it on the heap
scene->setSceneRect(0,0,200,200);
scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::blue);
QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
view->setScene(scene);
view->show();
<...>
}//your function ends here
```

In your version, the scene is created on the stack, so if you put this code anywhere in the class, the scene will die immediately at the end of the function. That's why it is white. If you allocate it on the heap, it will stay alive after the closing bracket, and you will be able to see it.

*Please do not forget to delete it after!*